# How do i search an element in a 1D List in Py3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a basic program that could tell the user if the element entered by them is present in the list entered by them or not.

My code:

```
a=(int(x) for x in input().split())
b=input('Enter the element you want to see if is present or not')
if b in a:
   print('Yes it is present')
else:
   print('Try again')
```

Output: Try Again (In all the cases)

Please help me correct this code and also tell me why `if b in a`  doesnt work but `b in a` works in the Python shell.

Thanks:)

Comment: Hint: `int` vs `str` comparison

Comment: @Chris_Rands Hi, thanks. It worked. changed `if b in a` to `if int(b) in a`